# Does a scheduled task in Windows that is triggered by an event run continually?

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, scheduled-tasks, events

I created a scheduled task in Windows 7 that is supposed to be triggered when an event happens.  Well, the event happened, and the action did not get performed?

Does a scheduled task in Windows that is triggered by an event run continually?

If so, should it get triggered if the event occurs during the period when Windows is starting from cold boot?  If not, can it be configured to look back 60 seconds?

I can break this up into separate questions if our community prefers, but I didn't want to spam... just let me know.

Comment: You seem pretty knowledgeable so this might be a bit obvious, but did you enable Task History in Task Scheduler and look at the task history for any clues? Have you tried manually invoking the task to ensure that your script/action can successfully run?

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Thanks for your questions. I did not enable Task History.  Is there a way to enable it for a single task, or only for all tasks?  I did manually invoke the task, and the task did nothing.  But would that be because the events are now in the past?  IOW, do event-based tasks respond to events only as they happen, or is there a bit of a look-back period?

Comment: I haven't been on Windows 7 for awhile, but I'm pretty sure it's the same as Windows 10 and Task History is an all or nothing feature.  Manually invoking the task will override the trigger event, so if you select Run and nothing happens, then I'd say there is a fault with the way the Action is setup.  As for looking backwards, you might be able to see your Event in the Event Viewer, but without more details of the actual Event you are triggering off of, I can't say for sure?

Comment: @spaceman-spiff It appears that in Win7, like Win10, it's all or nothing for the History.  So I enabled it.  When I manually run the task, it gets triggered regardless of the conditions (as you mentioned... I didn't know that... thanks!), and the history log indicates the action it performed.  But nothing happens.  So I simplified the action to simply be running a text editor.  The log says the executable of the text editor is launched, but I see nothing.  The Task Scheduler log even gives a PID for the editor that it launched, but I see no processes with that PID.

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Okay, I dove deeper. The process monitor was not running with escalated privileges.  Once I ran the escalated process monitor, I can see the text editor process being launched.  It gets launched with below normal priority and no window for it appears.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Ideas?

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Okay. I figured out the not-so-obvious. I'm trying to catch an error event, even if happens before Windows logs in a user.  So I set the task to run whether the user is logged in or not. This apparently runs any actions in some sort of "no person's land" of which I'm not familiar.  Even if logged in as admin, the actions are invisible.  Do you happen to know about this or have a pointer to more reading?

Comment: Task Scheduler actions don't always behave the way you expect them to.  .bat files are notoriously finicky depending on what is being called/invoked.  The issue might be that you need need to pass arguments to the executable in 'Actions' and set the full path in the arguments and/or define the path in the 'start in' section (batch files need this).  Also, might need to tinker with settings in the General tab (i.e. which User, logged on, highest privileges, etc...) Need more specific details on the action you are trying to help you more, though.

Comment: @spaceman-spiff For the action, I'll settle right now for just running `notepad.exe`! :)  I finally got that working iff (if and only if)  I configure the task to require a user to be logged in.  If I do not use that option, everything gets run as processes for which not even the admin account can see the windows of the running actions (notepad, or anything else).  The admin account, however, can see the processes running using an escalated process monitor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131627/discussion-between-spaceman-spiff-and-rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket).

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled Tasks should get invoked whenever the event Trigger conditions are met.
Depending on the Action that is being executed (e.g. Start a program) that may run continually until the process / application is terminated. Event based Triggers should be able to run from startup and before logon.

To troubleshoot if the Trigger (or Action) is failing:

- enable task history
- recreate the trigger / manually run the task
- check the task history for success/failures and details

If the Trigger is working, but the Action fails, it could be privileges or settings on the task General tab need to be adjusted and/or the 'Run with highest privileges' enabled and 'Hidden' is unchecked**.

Alternately, the Action may need arguments passed and/or a path defined. Batch files often require this and may need to be passed through `cmd`.  There's a good post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler

**It should be noted that `Run whether User is logged on or not` will not work for interactive applications.  The process will launch (e.g. Notepad.exe), but you will not be able to interact with it.